# Can data be saved between calls to the openCPU server?

Tags: persistence, opencpu

I understand that the interface to OpenCPU is RESTful. Nevertheless, I would like to save data between function calls, if possible.

I naively created the following package:

```
vals <- c()

fnInit <- function() {
  vals <<- c('a','b','c')
}
```

but I got the error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'vals' when I called the fnInit function. I understand why this is happening.

I then tried:

```
fnBoth <- local({
  vals <- c('a','b','c')
  function(which) {
    if (which == 0) {
      vals
    } else if (which == 1) {
      vals <<- c(vals,'d')
      vals
    }
  }
})
```

but every time I POST to the fnBoth function with which = 1, I get the same response: 
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

If I call the function again, I get the same answer. So, it would seem that the value vals is being reset each time.

My question is: Can data be saved between function calls? The above attempts are not meant to be exhaustive - maybe there's another technique? Or, should I simply save the value to disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, perhaps you can elaborate a bit on the type of application you wish to build.

OpenCPU supports chaining of function calls to calculate e.g. `f(g(x), h(y))`. This is done by passing the session ID of a completed call as an argument to a subsequent one. Have a look at the docs about argument formats: https://public.opencpu.org/api.html#api-arguments. It includes an example that illustrates this by calculating `summary(read.csv("mydata.csv"))`:

```
#upload local file mydata.csv
curl https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/utils/R/read.csv -F "file=@mydata.csv"

#replace session id with returned one above
curl https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/tmp/x067b4172/R/.val/print
curl https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/base/R/summary -d 'object=x067b4172'
```

The first request calls the `read.csv` function which returns a dataframe. In the last line, we call the `summary` function where we set the `object` argument equal to the output of the previous call (i.e. the data frame) by passing the session ID.

Comment: My user will be typing into a [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) form field which means that keystrokes are sent to the server as they are typed. I use the keystrokes to match against a 12,000 list of symbols, returning a list of those symbols that match (substring). I want to be able to retrieve the symbol list once rather than each time a keystroke triggers a call to the server.

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to your question? Seems like you just need handle `select2` in javascript? What is it you need from R/OpenCPU?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough. Yes, select2 is used in a javascript function. select2 makes ajax calls back to the server as the user enters data in the field. I am using ajax requests because I have found that I need to keep the symbol list on the server side; it's too big for the client side. So, I would like to use an  OpenCPU/R function on the server side to handle the ajax calls. It would do a lookup in the symbol list and returning matches. The  list (12,000 gene symbols) is stored in a database. I was trying to avoid loading those symbols each time this function is called.